# Do server-side pre-commit hooks work in GitLab community edition?

Tags: git, gitlab, pre-commit-hook

If I...

- have filesystem access to the server hosting the Git data of a GitLab Community Edition installation
- ...already have a working `pre-commit` hook for client-side installation, that blocks commits that fail specific rules (e.g. C files that have lines ending in whitespace)
- ...and then copy this `pre-commit` hook inside a `custom_hooks` folder under the repository's top-level folder, as [described here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/administration/custom_hooks.md)

...will I then be able to block people from pushing commits that violate the checks made by the hook?

```
 $ cd /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/someone/somerepo.git/
 $ mkdir custom_hooks
 $ sudo chown git.git custom_hooks
 $ cp /path/to/some/pre-commit-hook custom_hooks/pre-commit
 $ sudo chown git.git custom_hooks/pre-commit
 $ sudo chmod 755 custom_hooks/pre-commit
```

The hook in question already works client-side - but I am asking here because I am not sure of two things:

1. Is this functionality supported in the Community Edition of GitLab? The linked article above claims "CORE ONLY" in bold, which I am guessing means this doesn't work for the Community Edition?
2. Can a pre-commit hook function as-is on the server-side? Or do I need to adapt to using a different hook instead (`pre-receive`?) If so, an example adaptation would help a lot.

To make sure I am not creating another instance of the XY problem: what I am asking for is **a simple example of how to setup server-side GitLab Community Edition commit "filters" that are run when "git push" is executed from the committers**. I already have a working version of such a filter for client-side Git hook-ing (i.e. under hooks/pre-commit) - and am looking for a quick way to apply the same checking logic server-side.

P.S. Already tried the naive thing, of copying the hook as-is under the "hooks" folder on the server-side:  no change - commits go through without any checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is this functionality supported in the Community Edition of GitLab?
>      The linked article above claims "CORE ONLY" in bold, which I am
>      guessing means this doesn't work for the Community Edition?

Yes. You can add custom-hook script per repository or a [global script](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html#create-a-custom-git-hook-for-a-repository) for all repositories in Gitlab CE

> 2. Can a pre-commit hook function as-is on the server-side? Or do I need
>      to adapt to using a different hook instead (pre-receive?) If so, an
>      example adaptation would help a lot

A pre-commit hook will run before a commit, in server-side, this doesn't make sense. You need to transform your pre-commit into a pre-receive, pre-push, post-receive or update script hook. I believe, in your case, you need a pre-receive hook to check the commit before accept it in gitlab. [Here the documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) of all scripts hook types.